# Definite multivariate gaussian integral x e^{ (-0.5 x'T^{-1}x)}

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I am looking for the solution of a multivariate gaussian integral over a vector **x**. The dimension of the vectors **x** and **a** are p $\times$ 1 and  **T** is an p $\times$ p matrix. The integral is the following:

$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=a} x e^{ (-0.5 x'T^{-1}x)} d^p\bf{x}$$

I have tried to solve it with the cholesky decomposition and substitution, but the dimension of the solution is not a p $\times$ 1 vector. When a equals $\infty$ the solution is of course an p $\times$ 1 vector of zero's (since it is the expected value).

Since I am not very experienced in integrating over vectors, also a good reference about this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $x=\bf{x}$? If so, what does $x=a$ mean?

Comment: Yes, bold notation did not work in math mode. The vector a is the upper limit of the integral and is just an arbitrary vector.